IRA rollover to 403B to prevent RMD
I turned 72 this June, so my traditional and SEP IRA accounts will be subject to RMDs starting next year. Since I’m still working, my 403(b) account isn’t subject to RMDs. I was hoping to roll over my IRA accounts into my 403(b) to avoid the RMD requirement. However, Fidelity, where my 403(b) is held, informed me that my plan doesn’t allow rollovers from IRAs.
I’m trying to understand why some 403(b) plans allow such rollovers while others don’t. Is it a matter of plan design, and is there anything I can do about it? Also, are there any other ways to avoid taking RMDs from my IRAs?


I’m trying to understand why some 403(b) plans allow such rollovers while others don’t

Because there's no legal requirement to allow such rollovers, and no legal requirement to prohibit. So it's up to the plan. Some allow, some don't. Usually depends on the plan sponsor and administrator - what they're willing to support and what they're willing to pay for.

is there anything I can do about it?

Talk to your employer's benefits department whether they would agree to support that.

Also, are there any other ways to avoid taking RMDs from my IRAs?

No. The "R" in RMD stands for "Required". If you're OK with the tax hit and just don't want to take out the retirement money - you can try and convert to Roth IRA.

Another possibility: IF you would like to give some money to a qualified (i.e. 501(c)3) charity, you can transfer up to $100k/yr directly from your IRA as a QCD = Qualified Charitable Distribution; this counts as/toward your RMD, and is not taxable to you, but does of course decrease your IRA balance. And (as of recently) you can one-time put up to $50k into a charitable remainder annuity -- but I don't think that is deferrable, and the goal here appears to be deferring until (later than normal) retirement.
